# How to extend SocketIo ExecutionContext type. NestJs

Tags: typescript, socket.io, nestjs

I'm trying to extend the type of the ExecutionContext while using Socket.io.
I'll be brief, I have no idea how to do this.

While I'm using the **http context**, my code looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        request.user = await this.authService.verify(request.headers.authorization);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then I can get the extended "Request" type with the "user" field:

```js
@Controller("user")
export class UserController {
    constructor() {}

    @Get("all")
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    async getAll(@Req() request: Request) {
        const user = request.user; // => NO ERROR
        const users = [];
        return users;
    }
}
```

I will be able to do this by declaring a global class via the "index.d.ts" file:

```js
declare global {
    namespace NestJS { // this one works great
        export interface ExecutionContext {
            user?: IUserPayloadJWT
        }
    }

    namespace SocketIO { // how to properly do this one?
        export interface ExecutionContext {
            user?: IUserPayloadJWT
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use **ws socket** context, there is a problem with this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class WsAuth implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const client = context.switchToWs().getClient();
    client.user = await this.authService.verify(client.handshake.headers.authorization);
    return true;
  }
}
```

And my attempt to handle messages:

```js
@WebSocketGateway({
    namespace: "api/chat",
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    },

})
export class ChatGateway
        implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
    constructor(
        private readonly messageService: MessageService,
        private readonly userService: UserService,
        private readonly authService: AuthService,
        private readonly fileService: FileService
    ) {}

    @WebSocketServer()
    server: Server;

    userIdToSocketId: IUserIdToSocketId = {};

    async handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        const userData = await this.authService.verify(client.handshake.headers.authorization);
        this.userIdToSocketId[userData.id] = client.id;
    }

    @UseGuards(WsAuth)
    handleDisconnect(@ConnectedSocket() client) {
        delete this.userIdToSocketId[client.id];
    }

    @UseGuards(WsAuth)
    @SubscribeMessage("message")
    async handleMessage(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket, @MessageBody() message: TNewMessage) {
        const senderPayloadJWT: IUserPayloadJWT = client.user; // => Error: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, any>'. Did you mean 'use'?
    }
}
```